# GWT event servise browsers synchronization problem

Tags: gwt

I have implemented pretty simple application, using gwt and gwt event service 1.1.1, it sends some information to the server and waits for particular event to come back.

When application is opened in one browser window, it works fine.

When it is opened in two browser windows (the same browser and the same address: localhost:port/app or ip:port/app) on one machine, only one instance of my application receives event (UI reflects changes only in one window).

When it is opened in two different browsers, but with the same addresses (for instance, both are localhost:port/app), then both browsers receive events.

When it is opened in two windows of the same browser, but with different addresses (one is localhost:port/app, second is ip:port/app), then it also receives events.

So, could somebody provide any explanation to such behavior? And if is there some kind of workaround for this problem.

Thanks in advance, 
Alex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [gwt event service](http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/) on the server, right?

They claim to have "Only one open connection for event listening". So they actively check that one client has only one connection for sending events. They probably use web sessions to achieve this.

Since you open the same URL in the same browses in two tabs, this two tabs share the same session. There is no way around it. There are a lot of questions about this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=browser+tabs+session

**Update:**

It seems that gwt-event-service can be configured to support multiple sessions: use [SessionExtendedConnectionIdGenerator](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#UgGVH3fPz90/trunk/eventservice/src/main/java/de/novanic/eventservice/service/connection/id/SessionExtendedConnectionIdGenerator.java)

**Update 2:**

Use a config file like this: http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/source/browse/trunk/conf/eventservice.properties?r=265

Comment: Thanks, good to know about such opportunity. However, there is no official release of gwteventservice 1.2, I am not sure if it OK, to use trunk version. Btw, where should I put this .properties file in my war? Thanks.

Comment: Quote: The location of the properties file must be attached to the classpath of the server side application: https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/wiki/Configuration

Comment: Oh, my bad, Thank you again. Could you also give a hint how to build new jars from their trunk?

Comment: Great, everything seems to work fine. Thank you for your help.